# OCaml : filter map and put the values into a list

Tags: ocaml

I can filter my [map](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Map.Make.html) by key :

```
module PairKeys =
struct
  type t = string * string
  let compare (x0,y0) (x1,y1) =
    match String.compare x0 x1 with
    | 0 -> String.compare y0 y1
    | c -> c
end

module StringMap = Map.Make(PairKeys);;
....

let put_key_values_into_a_list (key_searched : string) = 
    StringMap.filter (fun key -> key = key_searched)
(* should return a list of the values in the filtered map *)
```

After that, I want to put the values into a list. 
How can I do this in OCaml?

Map.Make documentation : 
http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Map.Make.html

Thanks

Comment: You are using a map which cannot hold several values for the same key, i.e. it is *not* a [multimap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimap). Unless you change the filtering predicate, the code you want is roughly equivalent to `MyMap.find key_searched m` or to be more precise `[MyMap.find key_searched m]` (and the list will always be a singleton)

Comment: Maybe it's a good idea to include this information into the post, so people won't try to "optimize" the code :)

Comment: @Anton Trunov Alright thanks ! I improved my question.

Comment: Still, `key` matches the whole pair, not its 1st or 2nd component. What you want is probably something like `StringMap.filter (fun (key, _) _ -> key = key_searched)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `bindings` to retrieve the key/value pairs of a map and then further process them to extract the values. For example:

```
let put_key_values_into_a_list key_searched map =
    MyMap.filter (fun key _ -> key = key_searched) map
    |> MyMap.bindings |> List.split |> snd
```

We use `List.split` to convert a list of pairs into a pair of lists (one containing the keys, one the values) and then `snd` to extract the list of values.

Note also that `filter` takes a function with two arguments (the second of which gets ignored here).

Comment: What do you think about my answer ?

Comment: @AlexB It has the same functionality, with fewer temporary values being allocated, but reversing the result (which may or may not matter).

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I did it. I called fold after filter :

```
let put_key_values_into_a_list key_searched map =
    MyMap.fold (fun _ i acc -> i::acc) 
       (MyMap.filter (fun (x,_) _ -> x = key_searched) map) 
       []
```