# Wrong type of the expression

Tags: filter, ocaml, record

This question is strongly related to this [SE question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37512794/ocaml-filter-map-and-put-the-values-into-a-list). `MyMap` has been created the same way as `StringMap` from that question.

```
# lsc;;
- : (MyMap.key * testtype) list =
[(("", "Test1"),
  {name = ""; state = ""; region = "Test1a"});
(("", "Test1a"),
  {name = ""; state = ""; region = "Test1b"});
(("", "Test2"),
  {name = ""; state = ""; region = "Test2"})]
```

I want to create a function which will give me a filtered list from `lsc`. I want to filter it according to `(x, _) _`. For instance, it is equal to `Test1`, then the function will return the list of records

`[{name = ""; state = ""; region = "Test1a"}; {name = ""; state = ""; region = "Test1b"}]`

For the moment, I just want to filter `lsc` to get

```
[(("", "Test1"),
  {name = ""; state = ""; region = "Test1a"});
(("", "Test1a"),
  {name = ""; state = ""; region = "Test1b"})]
```

`MyMap.filter (fun (x,_) _ -> x="Test1") lsc;;` give me the following error :

```
Error: This expression has type (MyMap.key * testtype) list
       but an expression was expected of type
         'a MyMap.t = 'a Map.Make(PaireCles).t
```

From the [SE question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37512794/ocaml-filter-map-and-put-the-values-into-a-list), I thought it was the way to go, but I face always the same error. Is there a workaround for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Map.filter](https://ocaml.org/releases/4.10/htmlman/libref/Map.Make.html#VALfilter) function takes a function and a *map* data structure, not an association list, which you have. You can use [List.filter](https://ocaml.org/releases/4.10/htmlman/libref/List.html#VALfilter) to filter the list of key * value pairs,

```
List.filter (fun (x,_) -> x = "Test1") lsc
```

Comment: sorry, accidentally copy-pasted an extra argument from your function, fixed now